# Restore Firestore database to exact state found in previous export

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following https callable cloud function that imports all documents found in a backup.

```
    const path = `${timestamp}`;

    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();

    // we change the action for importDocuments
    const url = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/databases/(default):importDocuments`;
    const backup_route = `gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/${path}`;
    return client.request({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            inputUriPrefix: backup_route,
        }
    }).then(async (res: any) => {
        console.log(`Began backup restore from folder ${backup_route}`);
        return Promise.resolve(res.data.name);
    }).catch(async (e) => {
        return Promise.reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', e.message));
    })
```

I use to this function to restore the database to the exact state it was when it was exported.
The problem is that the import operation, does not affect documents that are not found in the export. So new documents added after the export will remain in the database.

The following quote from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) explains this behaviour:

> If a document in your database is not affected by an import, it will remain in your database after the import.

Is deleting the whole database before starting the import operation my only option? I can not find an operation that achieves the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided export mechansim isn't meant for what what most people would call a "backup" that would be "restored" in the event of data loss.  It's simply an export.  It useful for making a copy of a database to be imported elsewhere, making it easy to duplicate a database across environments without having to write a lot of code.

If you want a fresh copy of the database from an import with no other documents, you will have to wipe out what's there before importing.